# Getting error code 500 no matter what error I send from express using a error handler?

Tags: express

Using a custom error handler, specifically ts-custom-error but even when I roll my own, if I throw the following error after my routes to handle when someone puts in the wrong url/endpoint

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  throw HttpError.fromCode(404)
});

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

*edit added additional code

https://github.com/adriengibrat/ts-custom-error/blob/master/src/example/http-error.ts

I get the error message and stack ok, everything works in postman and browser for the body message, but in network on chrome and in the header it still shows a status code of 500. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your console/terminal for logs? 500 (Internal Server Error) means that there is something wrong with your server. Usually, an unhandled exception.

Are there any other code after this block? If not, your `thrown error` never gets handled anywhere, causing the 500 error.

You can use this instead:

```
res.status(404).send({ error: 'Your special error message here!' });
```